# Where can find the Iggeret Hashemad of the Rambam online in English?

Tags: rambam, internet, translation

Where can find the Iggeret Hashemad of the Rambam online in English? There are lots of scholarly resources talking about it, but I am unable to find the words of Rambam complete in translation.

Answer (score 3):

This letter of Rambam was translated into English by Leon D. Stitskin, and published in *Tradition* in two parts. The first part was published in Vol. 16 No. 4 (Summer 1977) under the title "Maimonides' *Maamar Kiddush Hashem*" and is available in the archives as a PDF [here](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2016/No.%204/Maimnides'%20Maamar%20Kiddush.pdf). The second part was published in Vol. 14 No. 2 (Fall 1973) under the title "Maimonides Letter on Apostasy" and can be viewed in the archives as a PDF [here](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2014/No.%202/Maimonides%20Letter%20on.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

You can read the translation (with notes) of Prof. Abraham Halkin (‘Epistles of Maimonides Crisis and Leadership’) [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=7zAlxRzcUoEC&lpg=PA67&ots=N007j1pEul&dq=maimonides%20epistle%20on%20martyrdom&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false). The translation is then followed by discussions of it by Prof. David Hartman.