Observance of mitzvot before brit milah
Many Jewish people today in the secular environment has no knowledge about the priorites toward a more religious life. If somebody discovers that he is Jewish, than what are the commandments that he can/should observe immediately and what are the ones that he cannot before the brit milah? Or alternatively, what mitzvot are prohibited without being circumscised?

Of interest, but only mildly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/137708/is-it-unacceptable-for-a-jew-to-not-keep-shabbat-even-if-they-are-slowly-trying/137712#137712

There are no commandments nowadays for which a bris milah is required.

Birkas kohanim?

@JoelK not afaik

Pri Chadash doesn't allow it. I don't know how we pasken lemaaseh

I don't remember seeing it in Mishna Berura.
